# Word for a small space/dwelling that is much larger on the inside than it appears from the exterior

Tags: single-word-requests, obscure-terms

I'm searching for a rare word that means a small space/dwelling that is much larger on the inside than it appears from the exterior. It has been in 2 stories I know of:

- shown as a magical tent: Ali Baba and The 40 Thieves,
- and most recently in the Harry Potter movies as Weasley's tent at the Quidditch World Cup. [*Perkin's tent / harrypotter.wikia.com*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Perkins%27s_tent).

Comment: “Dimensionally transcendental,” according to Dr Who.

Comment: Are you looking for the architectural term for the technique of creating this kind of illusion or a common word for such a building?

Comment: how about 'capacious'?

Comment: "Capacious" sounds wrong to me. It has the same root word as "capacity". For something magical I like the sound of "grotto". The meaning is not right. Its everyday meaning is just a cave. I've seen it used as a specialist term by cavers for a chamber within a cave.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BagOfHolding and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_satchel

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the architectural word. I heard it many years ago used by architects being interviewed on PBS, but was driving and couldn't write it down. By the time I got to a phone or computer it was unavailable. I even called the radio station and they couldn't help.

Comment: I want to use it for my interior design business...it's what I DO; I create space where there doesn't appear to be any.

Comment: I don't like the use of the word Tardis because it engenders the image of a blue telephone booth.

Comment: This word could be "non-euclidean", maybe?

Comment: I believe you are looking for the term [_spatiality_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatiality_(architecture)). I can post as an answer if you confirm also.

Answer (score 3):

Now accepted into the lexicon, and deriving from the Doctor Who example (I saw the first episode in 1963):

> **Tardis** *noun*
>
> ...
>
> 2A building or container that is larger inside than it appears to be
>   from outside.
>
> Example sentences:
>
> ‘It's a bit of a Tardis – two townhouses knocked together, with a long
>   gallery at the back where the garden used to be.’
>
> ‘Stretching away at the back of the house – like the rural equivalent
>   of a Tardis – are 17 acres of land.’
>
> ‘Though the building looks very spacious from the outside, the staff
>   have dubbed it the Tardis in reverse, as the interior is more compact
>   than you would imagine.’
>
> ‘The experimental house has been compared to a Tardis.’
>
> ‘The mind is like a Tardis, far bigger on the inside that it appears
>   on the outside.’

{[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tardis)}

Comment: It's an acronym, and therefore should be all-capped!!

Comment: I see you beat me to it :o)

Comment: @ Will Crawford You mean like 'radar'?

Comment: No, because that took *two* letters from RAdio. Not an acronym ;o)

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth: Laser might be a better example.

Comment: @Will Crawford [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acronym) gives a more felicitous definition than that given by some other online dictionaries: "acronym: a word (such as NATO, radar, or laser) formed from the initial letter or letters of each of the successive parts or major parts of a compound term". Note for instance that [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/abbreviations-initials-and-acronyms) includes 'radar' as an example while apparently not allowing it. But all this has been covered here long ago.

Comment: The problem with "Tardis" is that it is sci-fi related and does not fit the context of the examples (folk tales and magic) and it also requires a cultural knowledge.

Comment: Yes; this fits the title question only. I consider it worth mentioning that the word is now in the Lexicon; ELU is aimed primarily at the general Anglophone researcher rather than the individual SW-seeker. _And many words require some cultural knowledge; would you say that 'Tardis' is very rare (which I would certainly agree would make it off-topic)?_

Answer (score 0):

I love *tardis*, first episode about 1977. Was 1963 the second doctor? If it's reached the lexicon,  I think it should be "tardis" like "laser." In Doctor Who lingo: Time And Relative Dimensions In Space

I think you're stuck using an adverb unless you like *tardis* as a noun, such as:

"This apartment is surprisingly spacious."

The other option I like, as long as were talking architecture/real estate is **maximizes**, but this doesn't generalize.

*This yard maximizes it's space.*

*Because of extensive shelving, the walk-in closet maximizes its potential.*

As an aside, esoteric words are rarely a good idea for marketing.